# How to combine two JSON in MULE?

Tags: json, mule

I have just started working on MULE and I am trying to combine 2 JSONs (say 1 is coming from http post and another is set as Payload in sub flow). Now how can i combine the 2 JSONs.

I tried with custom Transformer but no success.So please suggest how can i implement or any relevant reference doc for same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That depends on how you are getting the payload from different source ..

for example if you are using Scatter-Gather and getting the payload from 2 different source in parallel, you can easily use `<combine-collections-transformer doc:name="Combine Collections"/>` or `<collection-aggregator failOnTimeout="true" doc:name="Collection Aggregator"/>` to combine both the JSON into one payload..

This will combine both the JSON into one payload